# Can I render the render border with full quality

Tags: rendering, camera, compositing-nodes, resolution, render-border

Let's say the image is my project.
I got my composition and camera done and got it rendered.
Now I want a close up of my shot without changing the camera perspective and such.
Can I render the render border only, but make it full quality?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi rendering in Blender depends by camera view. Pablo Vazquez did Amaranth patch for what you're looking for:
https://pablovazquez.art/amaranth/

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. It is exactly what im looking for. Too bad it's not for 2.8

Comment: I still haven't tested 2.8, I don't know if there are new controls for that. In the other case you have to create a second camera. Best wishes